# Как остановить телеграм бота? Telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Всем доброго времени суток!
Прошу у Вас помощи в создании телеграм бота для личного использования.
Я хочу чтобы мой телеграм бот мог останавливаться.
Ниже привел пример

```
print('run')
bot.polling()
print('continue')
```

В консоль выводит "run", а вот continue уже не выводит. То есть это строчка выполняется пока я не крашну бота насильно.
Как можно завернуть "bot.polling" так, чтобы при каком-либо условии можно было его остановить?

Хочу сделать по типу этого:

```
while a == 0:
    bot.polling()
    if a > 0:
        bot.stop_bot()
        break
```

Но это так не работает.
Призываю на помощь ветеранов. Спасибо!

Comment: После вызова `bot.polling()` код зациклен. Вам нужно посмотреть какие есть методы у самого бота и через них вызывать его остановку. Методы можно вызывать в методе-обработчике команд бота или в отдельном потоке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['stop'])
def stop():
    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Да, Вам нужно в любом случае добавить хотя бы новый декоратор, так как после `bot.polling()` зацикливает код, пока программа не остановится вручную или аварийно:

`@bot.message_handler(content_types=['stop']) def stop(message): bot.stop_bot()`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй вызвать bot.stop_polling()
Изменяй переменную 'a' на 1 или 2, отталкиваясь от того, какую команду ты хочешь чтобы программа выполняла.

```
a = 1
if a == 0:
    bot.stop_polling()
elif a == 1:
    bot.polling()
```